# Intellij IDEA - Copy code without unnecessary indentation?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I want to write and test my code before I post an answer on a Stack Exchange. If I copy the working code over to Stack Exchange, it is indentated with too many spaces before each line.

How can I transfer the code over without the unneeded indentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try **Ctrl + Shift + Alt** + [mouse/touchpad selection]

it will select code in "column" mode. Means, no unneeded spaces from the left of right side, will copy the rectangular selection.

Comment: Also, I just found out you can keep your scrollwheel pressed and drag, that works the same way.

Comment: Cmd + Shift + Option + Mouse on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can press `shift+tab` as many times as needed to remove extra indentation, then copy, then `ctrl+z` to undo.

[image: screenshare]

result:

```php
/**
 * Process clumsy/user-submitted values to extract numeric from them
 *
 * Helper::recognizeNumber('1.123.456,789 0123 456 ') // => 1123456.7890123456
 * Helper::recognizeNumber(' -12,30 ')                // => -12.3
 * Helper::recognizeNumber('12,34 ', round: 0)      // => -12
 */
public static function recognizeNumber(mixed $number): float
{
    if (! $number) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    if (str_contains($number, '.') && str_contains($number, ',')) {
        $positionOfDot  = strpos($number, '.');
        $positionOfComa = strpos($number, ',');

        // dot is thousand separator
        if ($positionOfDot < $positionOfComa) {
            $number = str_replace('.', '', $number);
        } else {
            // coma is thousand separator
            $number = str_replace(',', '', $number);
        }
    }

    $number = str_replace(',', '.', $number);
    $number = preg_replace('/[^\d.-]+/', '', $number);

    return (float)$number;
}
```

Although I wish there was an Intellij plugin for that.